# Algorithms for finding minimal ball covers

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

My question is whether there exist algorithms to determine a minimal (or close to minimal) cover of a Riemannian manifold (or some subset thereof) with balls of a fixed radius r>0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a version of set-cover, the problem is NP-hard.
The following is a special case:

> **(1)** Chepoi, Victor, and Bertrand Estellon. "Packing and covering $\delta$-hyperbolic spaces by balls." In *Approximation, Randomization, and Combinatorial Optimization.* Algorithms and Techniques, pp. 59-73. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2007.
>   [Springer link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-74208-1_5).
>   
>   "In this note, we consider the problem of covering and packing by balls and
>   union of balls of hyperbolic metric spaces and graphs."

---

> **(2)** Singhof, Wilhelm. "Minimal coverings of manifolds with balls." *Manuscripta Mathematica* 29, no. 2-4 (1979): 385-415.
>   [Springer link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01303636).

My understanding is that Singhof links the covering number $B(M)$ of a manifold $M$
to the Lusternik-Schnirelmann category $\operatorname{cat} M$ of a manifold.

You might find later literature, especially for (2), that relies on or 
expands upon these results.